# Turning things to sand

Tags: science-in-society, alternate-reality

I'm trying to figure out what would preserve the buildings, but would turn the landscape of most of North America (From Halfway into Mexico to slightly into Canada) to a sand covered desert (which is then followed by a completely unrelated pole shift). Also, nuclear weapons are out of the picture.

It doesn't have to be man made, and should be relatively quick (in the span of a few months max) it would also kill 99.9% of people on the continent. Technology is more advanced then ours in certain aspects and lacking in others (Only one country/empire had access to Nuclear power, and did not share it. The rest of the world resorted to more archaic methods or Geo-thermal power).

Comment: Do you really mean everything from Alert, Nunavut to the Panama Canal? North America is quite varied.

Comment: I mean from slightly above the Canadian border, and down through a sizable portion of Mexico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the obvious consequence of a self-limiting [grey goo event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_goo). All life and organic material was consumed, and the self-destruct limit was reached and the nanobots disintegrated. Unfortunately, the programmers made a slight error in their limit counter, but there's nobody around to criticize them.

Well, that's half the job done. The other half, and arguably the harder, is getting rid of all that pesky water that's lying around. Without organic processes available to bind soil together, erosion will be greatly enhanced, although this probably won't make all that much difference before the remnant cities collapse. Nonetheless, not many areas have large amounts of sand (as opposed to fine rock flour) as their dominant ground material. Sand is a pretty particular kind of rock, with roughly spherical grains of a rather particular size. Rock flour, of the kind which makes up most soil, is much smaller, and will tend to hold water due to capillary action, creating mud or hard pan. Where it dries out it will form a fine dust which will blow around and make life miserable for the tourists.

Comment: I like this idea a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Mismanagement of the land on a massive scale. This takes a number of years before it really comes into effect, but not all that many years. You would have time to avert it if noticed in time, but the political environment that would allow it to happen in the first place is unlikely to be able to stop it in time.

This is known as [desertification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desertification) and comes with a map of vulnerable areas

> The immediate cause is the loss of most vegetation. This is driven by a number of factors, alone or in combination, such as drought, climatic shifts, hi tillage for agriculture, overgrazing and deforestation for fuel or construction materials. Vegetation plays a major role in determining the biological composition of the soil. Studies have shown that, in many environments, the rate of erosion and runoff decreases exponentially with increased vegetation cover. Unprotected, dry soil surfaces blow away with the wind or are washed away by flash floods, leaving infertile lower soil layers that bake in the sun and become an unproductive hardpan. 
>   [image: desertification vulnerability]

As you can see a significant proportion of North America is considered to be vulnerable to this effect. Of course the vulnerable area will move with the expanding deserts to cover an ever larger area as the deserts grow.

Comment: Note the *dust bowl* where this was hqppening in North America before.